# Rails shows "WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" from a RestKit POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, ruby-on-rails-3, restkit

When I try to POST from `RestKit`, there is a warning in Rails console:

```
Started POST "/friends" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-16 09:58:10 +0800
Processing by FriendsController#create as */*
Parameters: {"friend"=>{"myself_id"=>"m001", "friend_id"=>"f001"}}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.7ms)  INSERT INTO `friends` (`friend_id`, `myself_id`) VALUES ('f001', 'm001')
(1.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/friends/8
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

Here is client code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[attributes setObject: @"f001" forKey: @"friend_id"];
[attributes setObject: @"m001" forKey: @"myself_id"];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:attributes forKey:@"friend"];
[[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/friends" params:params delegate:self];
```

How can I get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can safely remove the warnings with the following:

```
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
```

This should go into every Rails API controller that you have, or if you have a `base_controller` for all API controllers then put it there.

If you can also access your app through a web browser then do not put this line in the `application_controller` as you will be creating a security vulnerability.

It is safe to remove `csrf` for API calls as the particular vulnerability can only be executed through a web browser.

**Update 16th December 2013**

I've seen some links to this answer and some other content which suggests a clarification. An API may be vulnerable to CSRF if you use web based authentication methods to authenticate the API - e.g. sessions or cookies.

There is some good detail in [Is your Web API susceptible to a CSRF exploit?](https://mathieu.fenniak.net/is-your-web-api-susceptible-to-a-csrf-exploit/).

My advice still stands for users of RestKit as user credentials are unlikely to be based on sessions or cookies but rather usernames or api keys.

If your API can be authenticated with session or cookies then you should avoid skipping `: verify_authenticity_token` and you should think about moving to api key based authentication.

If your API can be authenticated with a username and password that is also used to authenticate on the web there is still a potential exploit, although it is less serious as it would require the user to type in their username and password to your site in the HTTP Auth challenge box while visiting the site with the exploit. Again, for the best security you should think about moving to api key based authentication.

It's worth noting that I don't agree that you need to add `:only => [:your_method]` for additional protection, provided that you have isolated api controllers, your api is not mixed with your web responses and you are not using session or cookies. If these are in place you can safely add the `skip_before_filter` into a `base_controller` for your api.

Comment: To avoid opening a big hole, I recommend skiping the verification just for your method. `skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token :only => [:your_method]`

Comment: for those cut and pasting the above code: `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:your_method]` Marc forgot a comma. DIdn't see an edit button.

Comment: This really helped understand this issue and how to solve it if you have a Rails API that uses tokens (alongside controllers that respond to regular web requests): https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/343