# AngularJS - $http POST with Rails 3.2.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I'm building a simple Contact Management app with Crud using AngularJS 1.0.0rc8.

Getting a list of currently existing contacts is no problem, but while attempting to save a new Contact to the server, a new row is created - complete with the correct id, created_at, and updated_at values - but the rest of the models data is ignored.

Here is a screenshot to show what I mean:

[image]

As you can see, numbers 4 and 5 were given the Id's but first_name, last_name, and phone_num were not saved to the database.

I am using a **$scope.addContact** function within the Controller that deals with the object.

Here is the entire code for the Contact List Controller:

```
'use strict';

function ContactListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/contacts').success(function(data) {
    $scope.contacts = data;
  });    

  $scope.addContact = function(data) {      

    $http.post('/contacts/', data).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        data.first_name = $("#new_contact_first_name").val();
        data.last_name = $("#new_contact_last_name").val();
    });

    this.newFirstName = '';
    this.newLastName = '';
  };

};
```

After clicking **'Save'** on the new-contact.html partial, the Object is logged to the Console, if I inspect its contents, than sure enough the values are collected - notice Jimi Hendrix is there:

[image]

Here is the form as it appears in the new-contact.html template:

```
<form id="contact_form" ng-submit="addContact()">
            <input type="text" id="new_contact_first_name" name="newContactFirstName" ng-model="newFirstName" placeholder="First Name"></br>
            <input type="text" id="new_contact_last_name" name="newContactLastName" ng-model="newLastName" placeholder="Last Name"></br>
            <input type="button" id="contact_submit_btn" value="Add Contact" class="btn btn-primary">               
        </form>
```

The **addContact()** function is fired after the form is submitted with JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       

        $("#contact_submit_btn").click(function(){          
            $("#contact_form").submit();
        });
    });
```

---

*(Something tells me that I may not be using the ng-model attributes correctly.)*

**Any ideas on where I am going wrong with this?  Or ideas on how I can better go about implementing this design?**

Thanks.

---

### UPDATE BELOW:

**Here is my entire updated controller code - with help from Sathish:**

```
 // contacts controllers

'use strict';

function ContactListCtrl($scope, $http, Contacts) {   

  $scope.contacts = Contacts.index();  

  $scope.addContact = function() {
        var newContact = {
            first_name: $scope.newContactFirstName,
            last_name: $scope.newContactLastName
        };

        var nc = new Contacts({ contact: newContact });

        nc.$create(function() {
            $scope.contacts.push(nc);
            // now that the contact is saved, clear the form data
            $scope.newContactFirstName = "";
            $scope.newContactLastName = "";
            })
        }

};

ContactListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'Contacts'];


function ContactDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams, Contacts) {  
    $scope.contact = Contacts.get( {contact_id: $routeParams.contact_id} ); 
}

ContactDetailCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Contacts'];
```

<strike>I am now receiving the error: Unknown Provider for Contacts.  Here is a screenshot of the error</strike>

Ok, I managed to fix that error by providing a **ngResource** to the main App file.  Here's what it looks like:

```
// main app javascript file

'use strict';

angular.module('contactapp', ['ngResource']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/contacts', {template: 'assets/app/partials/contact-list.html',   controller: ContactListCtrl}).
      when('/contacts/new', {template: 'assets/app/partials/new-contact.html',   controller: ContactListCtrl}).
      when('/contacts/:contact_id', {template: 'assets/app/partials/contact-detail.html', controller: ContactDetailCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/contacts'});
}]);
```

<strike>I am receiving a new error:  **WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity**</strike>

Alright, managed to fix that problem too by adding a callback to the API controller:
[Rails shows "WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" from a RestKit POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167956/rails-shows-warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-from-a-restkit-post)

<strike>**Now I am back to the original problem.  When the create method is called, a new row is saved to the database, but the models data is not.**</strike>

**Awesome... finally got this thing working.**

The problem was the **$scope.addContact** function.  It was using the 'name' of the input instead of the **ng-model** binding called 'newFirstName' and 'newLastName' that resides in the template.

Here's what the updated function looks like:

```
$scope.addContact = function() {
        var newContact = {
            first_name: $scope.newFirstName,
            last_name: $scope.newLastName
        };

        var nc = new Contacts({ contact: newContact });

        nc.$create(function() {
            $scope.contacts.push(nc);
            // now that the contact is saved, clear the form data
            $scope.newFirstName = "";
            $scope.newLastName = "";
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be better implemented using a Contacts service. Please define a Contacts service in app/assets/javascripts/services.js.erb as shown below:

```
var servicesModule = angular.module('<your app name>',
  [<list of modules needed by this app>]);

servicesModule.factory('Contacts', function($resource) {
  var ContactsService = $resource('/contacts/:contact_id', {}, {
    'create': { method: 'POST' },
    'index': { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    'update': { method: 'PUT' },
    'destroy': { method: 'DELETE' }
  });
  return ContactsService;
});
```

Change the addContact method in the controller as shown below:

```
  function ContactListCtrl($scope, $http, Contacts) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    $scope.addContact = function () {
      var newContact = {
        first_name: $scope.newContactFirstName,
        last_name: $scope.newContactLastName
      };

      var nc = new Contacts({ contact: newContact });
      nc.$create(function() {
        $scope.contacts.push(nc);
        // now that the contact is saved, clear the form data.
        $scope.newContactFirstName = "";
        $scope.newContactLastName = "";
      });
    };
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
  ContactListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'Contacts'];
```

In addition to this, you can simplify the `$http.get(...)` part also. You can use `Contacts.index();`

**Note:**

- If you gave `ng-app="MyAppName"` then please replace `<your app name>` with `MyAppName`.
- `<list of modules needed by this app>` needs to the replaced by a comma-separated list of strings representing any modules needed by your application.

Comment: Shouldn't Contacts be injected in to the controller?

Comment: @DominicMitchell, yes. Missed mentioning it. Will edit the answer to inject Contacts into the controller. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Sathish - thanks so much for your help.  I implemented your code and I am receiving an 'Unknown Provider' error for Contacts.  I created an Update section at the bottom of my original post with more details.

Comment: @Sathish - scratch that last comment.  It's all good now, thanks for your help with the services.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `attr_accessible` on your model. With new 3.2.3 rails all model attributes became protected from mass-assignment by default.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mark.  I don't believe that's the problem, though, because all of my model attributes are listed after the attr_accessible helper.