# WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity in case of API development

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, token, csrf

I am right now developing web **APIs** with Ruby on Rails. When the Rails app receives POST request without any csrf token, the following error message shall happen. Because the app has no views.

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

So my question is how can I escape csrf token check safely in this case?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: My question was able to be solved by the past Q and A below. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167956/rails-shows-warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-from-a-restkit-post

Comment: This may help you!
Take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181340/rails-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-when-making-a-post-request

Answer (score 66):

You can do this by adding

```
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
```

to your controller. This way all incoming requests to the controller skips the :verify_authenticity_token filter.

Comment: Any drawbacks from this solution? Is it the default thing to do for APIs? In application_controller there's an API "hint":
`# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.`

Comment: Yes, if your application runs only in browser, removing this will allow for CROSS-SITE-REQUEST-FORGERY http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: And for JSON APIs that are tied to your Rails Views, I recommend you use CSRF protection. But for APIs that are consumed by mobile clients or some other application separate from Rails app, this should be turned off.

Comment: And lastly the `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` essentially says that when an unverified request comes in, it should not reset the session completely. So for the next verified request, the session will be present. There are various options for handling unverified requests. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html

Comment: My app is being access only through JSON from my mobile clients. So no browser, no html views. I think I understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

For rails 4 it should be

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:one_or_two_actions_here]
```

Note that you should avoid skipping verify_authenticity_token on all actions of your controller, instead use the option `only` to skip only where you have to. [See the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html)