# Controller does not find id to redirect to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this controller:

```
class SalesmenController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_salesman, only: [:show]


  def show
    authorize! :read, @salesman
  end

  def create
    @salesman = Salesman.new(params_salesman)
    authorize! :create, @salesman
    if @salesman.save
      flash[:notice] = "Salesman saved!"
      redirect_to company_salesman_path(@salesman.id)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Cannot create salesman!"
      render :new
    end
  end

private
  def params_salesman
    params.require(:salesman).permit(:name, :company_id)
  end

  def find_salesman
    @salesman = Salesman.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I'm passing a test to see if everything will be correct when it comes to the controllers. The test is as follows:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SalesmenController, type: :controller do
   include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

   before(:each) do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:owner]
    @current_owner = FactoryGirl.create(:owner)
    sign_in @current_owner
    @current_company = FactoryGirl.create(:company, owner: @current_owner)
  end

describe "POST #create" do
    before(:each) do
      salesman = FactoryGirl.create(:salesman, company: @current_company)
      post :create, params: {:company_id => @current_company.id, salesman: { name: salesman.name, company_id: @current_company.id } }
    end

    it "redirect to new team" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

    it "Create team with right attributes" do
      expect(Salesman.last.company).to eql(@current_company)
      expect(Salesman.last.name).to eql(@salesman[:name])
    end
  end
end
```

When I pass this test a strange error happens, it seems that in the controller it is not able to get the id when I indicate in the to redirect to the show route. The error is:

```
 1) SalesmenController POST #create redirect to new team
     Failure/Error: redirect_to company_salesman_path(@salesman.id)

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :company_id=>390, :controller=>"salesmen"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

It's missing the salesman's id, I did not understand why and I do not know how to get out of this situation.

My routes are:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :companies do
    resources :salesmen
    resources :goals do
      resources :days
    end
  end
  devise_for :owners, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
redirect_to company_salesman_path(:id => @salesman.id)
```

or

```
redirect_to company_salesman_path(@salesman)
```

hope this would help.

Comment: The first one helped ... but now when I pass the tests it says: Failure / Error: expect (response) .to have_http_status (: success)
       expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 302

Comment: make the response status :found instead of :success.

Comment: I think this [link](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/10/13/list-of-rails-status-code-symbols/) would help, look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883254/http-status-code-302) too