# Some Rails ActiveStorage Photos Not Deleting on Production (Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

So on my Rails 7 app I have a `Product` which `has_many` `photos`.

I show them with links to delete individual photos on the `photos#edit` page.  Most of them work, but weirdly enough some of them throw up a CSRF error.

The ERB for the deletion link looks like this:

```
<% product.photos.each do |photo| %>
  <div class="inline-block">
    <%= image_tag(photo, width: 25) %>
    <%= button_to '<i class="fas fa-times-circle fa-xs" style="margin-left: -10px; position: relative; top: -10px"></i>'.html_safe, 
                  product_photo_path(product, photo), 
                  method: :delete, 
                  class: "btn-invisible",
                  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } 
      %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The delete link renders into HTML like this:

```
<img width="25" src="https://lgw-2023.herokuapp.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBWWc9IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--6a79941d68ebd75d1a09941f6081eba67e7fd511/Recess%20Kit.jpg" />
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/products/113/photos/760"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" autocomplete="off" /><button class="btn-invisible" data-confirm="Are you sure?" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-times-circle fa-xs" style="margin-left: -10px; position: relative; top: -10px"></i></button><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="K7hCXTJyZPcRi528zAhFtPnfa1bjYg-WphGGb97lnSOh6nNw8ZPFWHhhvUy-CZ1MBYagtxh9Hqs78IsNlTrPaw" autocomplete="off" /></form>
```

Here's what my `heroku logs` say:

```
2023-11-22T03:42:36.183342+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-11-22T03:42:36.183279 #2]  INFO -- : [bef85162-98ad-485c-b57c-6b36af83a64a] Started DELETE "/products/113" for 70.181.107.14 at 2023-11-22 03:42:36 +0000
2023-11-22T03:42:36.184058+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-11-22T03:42:36.184020 #2]  INFO -- : [bef85162-98ad-485c-b57c-6b36af83a64a] Processing by ProductsController#destroy as HTML
2023-11-22T03:42:36.184099+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-11-22T03:42:36.184072 #2]  INFO -- : [bef85162-98ad-485c-b57c-6b36af83a64a]   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "product"=>{"name"=>"V11 Animal", "product_name_id"=>"14", "sku"=>"", "MSRP"=>"629.99", "lowest_price"=>"629.99", "model"=>"V11", "color"=>"", "dimensions"=>"", "voltage"=>"", "voltage_category"=>"N/A", "photos"=>[""], "historical_models"=>"", "description"=>"", "active"=>"1"}, "id"=>"113"}
2023-11-22T03:42:36.184545+00:00 app[web.1]: W, [2023-11-22T03:42:36.184513 #2]  WARN -- : [bef85162-98ad-485c-b57c-6b36af83a64a] Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
2023-11-22T03:42:36.184743+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-11-22T03:42:36.184722 #2]  INFO -- : [bef85162-98ad-485c-b57c-6b36af83a64a] Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 340)
2023-11-22T03:42:36.185320+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2023-11-22T03:42:36.185280 #2] FATAL -- : [bef85162-98ad-485c-b57c-6b36af83a64a]
2023-11-22T03:42:36.185321+00:00 app[web.1]: [bef85162-98ad-485c-b57c-6b36af83a64a] ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.):
```

The `photos_controller.rb` looks like this:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    @photo = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
    product = Product.find(@photo.record_id)
    @photo.purge
    redirect_to edit_product_path(product)
  end

end
```

Can anyone see why certain photos are throwing up a CSRF error and others aren't?

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers in this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181340/rails-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-when-making-a-post-request?rq=2)? It might just work with `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :destroy`.

Comment: I tried putting `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :destroy` in the `photos_controller.rb` but I still got the same ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.)  But when I put it in `products_controller.rb` it deleted the whole product (instead of the picture)....?

Comment: According to your HTML, you want to send a `DELETE` request to `/products/113/photos/76`. But it is sending a `DELETE` request to `/products/113` only (which is probably deleting the product instead of the photo).

So the form you are showing us in the rendered HTML does not seem to be called? Do you have maybe another form that is called when clicking that button (that is calling `/products/113`)?