# Session not maintained on post request, angular2, rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, session, post, get

I'm trying to get my head around the difference of how sessions are handled between **GET** and **POST** request.

In rails I'm setting a current_user with a session variable. This works fine for all get requests **BUT** when I do a POST it seems like the session variable is not carried over. This results in `current_user = null`

I guess these pictures explains it well.

Cookies on a working **GET** request - [Working get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/velUJ.png)

Cookies on a **NOT** working **POST** request - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRuZk.png)

- Why is that?
- Do I have to change the header in the angular2 request?
- Is it a setting in rails to allow sessions with POST requests.

Here is some of my code...

***Angular: Version 1*** - Doesn't set my **current_user**

```
    postSomeData( id : number ){
        return this._http.post( "/api/something/" + id,
                  JSON.stringify("{id: id}") )
                  .map( response => response.json() )
    }
```

***Angular: Version 2*** - Doesn't set my **current_user**

```
postSomeData( id : number ){
   let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.post( 
    "/api/lists/private/translation/" + id, 
    JSON.stringify("{id: id}"), 
     { headers: headers, withCredentials: true } )
                .map( response => response.json() )
  }
```

***Rails: ApplicationController***

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

- Rails 5.0.0.1
- Angular 4.0.5

Comment: Hey! I'm facing exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

People usually do something like this in the ApplicationController or in a helper:

```
def set_user
  unless @current_user.present?
    @current_user = User.where(id: session[:user_id]).take || User.new
  end
end
```

Then you can query if the user has any relations or has an ID, etc...

Comment: Thanx for you answer but I don't think that would help me in this case. My problem is that session[:user_id] is null after my POST request so I don't get the user I want. I added two images in the description which explains my issue pretty well.

Comment: People first need to sign in in order to send the post requests right?

Comment: Then in your ApplicationController add `before_action :set_user` so you always have a `@current_use`

Comment: re: @Ealco I was actually prototyping so I had no login functionality. Does a user need to be login in order for a POST request to keep the session?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the very same situation. Turned out that the problem is with the rails server, not angular.

When I make http post request the following statement shows in the logs and my session gets terminated.

> WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

I searched for this and the discussion on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040964/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-in-case-of-api-development) thread did help me.

Adding the following line in my controller allowed me to make http post reqests.

```
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: That's a great insight. I ended up using cookies as a temporary solution back then. But I'll come back to this. Sounds like this is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: OH NO: Adding the skip before filter will leave you exposed to CSRF attacks. What you need to do is to enable your angular code to pick up the CSRF token from rails and to pass that along with your post request. Not sure how you can do that with agular, but perhaps you can pass in flags to your angular code?