# Can't verify CSRF token authenticity Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf

I am developing a simple site which lets admins create questions and users solve them. I use ActiveAdmin for the admin part and simple AJAX calls for the user solving part. Trying to login via ActiveAdmin::Devise was successful at first but login out was not possible. I erased all cookies and since then I am not able to make POST actions without a CSRF token authenticity exception. I have the correct meta_tags within the head of my application.html.erb, declared jquery_ujs (other threads say its a common issue) and in both POST actions the authenticity token exists. I tried even avoiding the verification via *skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token* but the ActiveAdmin Login and POST Example continue failing. The logs are below, you can see that the tokens exist. I also show the Gemfile in case that any of those break something with the CSRF.

- Rails Version [4.1.0]
- Ruby Version [2.1]
- Phusion Passenger Version [4.0.41]

Thanks in advance.

**application.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <title>Introducción Matematicas</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all"%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:300,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

---

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
//= require_tree .
```

**Aplication Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  #skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
        u.permit :name,:college, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
      end
  end
end
```

**Admin Login Log**

```
INFO -- : Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aRZK3470X6+FJPANEuHAiwVW4NZwMzCkXtoZ1qlhQ0o=", "admin_user"=>{"email"=>"omar@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
WARN -- : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
INFO -- : Completed 401 Unauthorized in 110ms
INFO -- : Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aRZK3470X6+FJPANEuHAiwVW4NZwMzCkXtoZ1qlhQ0o=", "admin_user"=>{"email"=>"omar@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
WARN -- : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
INFO -- :   Rendered vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-a460d8d2ab37/app/views/active_admin/devise/shared/_links.erb (2.0ms)
INFO -- :   Rendered vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-a460d8d2ab37/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/active_admin_logged_out (73.0ms)
INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 302ms (Views: 80.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**Simple POST via AJAX Log**

```
INFO -- : Processing by QuestionsController#check_question as JS
INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "que_id"=>"44", "authenticity_token"=>"CjaAx+B36JPc1PUIhta0vIuOTKX4UhrFWlmYHAd+KWY=", "question"=>{"id"=>"169"}, "commit"=>"Verificar Respuesta", "id"=>"6"}
WARN -- : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
INFO -- :   Rendered answers/_answer.html.erb (1.2ms)
INFO -- :   Rendered questions/check_question.js.erb (17.0ms)
INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 94ms
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
#gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'mysql2', "0.3.15"
gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
gem 'minitest'
```

Comment: Similar answer can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734243/rails-csrf-protection-angular-js-protect-from-forgery-makes-me-to-log-out-on). Credits: @hungyuhei

Answer (score 10):

`skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`

**Whoa,** don't do this. That's a total hack, and if you leave that in your code accidentally you've just created a serious security problem.

So, why did you delete your cookies? If I read your question correctly it's because your logout function was broken? How about you find out why logout isn't working and fix that instead. Probably not a good idea to go and create another problem (bypassing CSRF authentication) instead of fixing the original problem.

In the meantime restart the local development server and start a new tab in your browser. See if that makes the CSRF stuff at least go away and then go back to the logout problem.

Comment: The skip_before_filter was just to check what happened to other POST actions besides the login if the CSRF check was ignored (the server is in a local network, just my team has access, that is why I used the skip_before_filter hack), as you advice I will start by checking whats happening with the login and logout actions. If I find the issue I will post the result here :) Thanks @jefflunt

Comment: Oh, I figured it was just on an internal box. I just meant that things sometimes have a way of being forgotten after a long debugging sessions, and that one would be bad if it made it to production.

Comment: I seem to be having this same issue. If I'm logged in (Devise) there is no error.

Comment: I've got the same issue with ActiveAdmin login, mine was working for months without any issue on server, suddenly this become an issue, Did you had any luck solving this?

Comment: It is safe, if we [write API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167956/rails-shows-warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-from-a-restkit-post) .. Right ?

Answer (score 6):

Usually, you will have this issue when calling from AJAX.  You can simply put to send the token along with the post

```
headers : {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') // X-CSRF-TOKEN is used for Ruby on Rails Tokens
}
```

in your ajax post call, and be sure you have

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

in your HTML.

**Don't ever use this**

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the below gem https://github.com/jsanders/angular_rails_csrf it will take of the rest.