# Ruby - RESTful API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, restful-architecture

I'm trying to build a RESTful API using ruby and its RESTful routes.  I am completely new to ruby (this is my first project) and am finding it has a very steep learning curve.  I have tried to generate a simple user model and am attempting to create a CRUD example with it.  Currently I am stuck on creating the user object inside the controller from a posted json object.  I have implemented my own create method and am trying to have it echo back the json object that I post to it.  For some reason all I get is a 404 back and a page that shows my routs.  Here is the model, controller, routes file and migration file that I used to implement the API, why doesn't it work as expected?

user model:

```
#the user model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :password, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :presence =>true
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

end
```

db migration file:

```
#migration file
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :last_name, :null => false
      t.string :email, :null => false
      t.string :first_name, :null => false
      t.string :password, :null => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Routes File:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # Define api routes for user
  namespace :api do
   resources :user, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
  end
end
```

user controllers file:

```
#user controller 
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def create
    puts params
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't my post object being displayed to the console?

Comment: is user_controller.rb in app/controllers/api folder ?

Comment: I put the controller in the api folder I now get a 500 internal server error @nyzm

Comment: This is the new error that I am getting:

`Started POST "/api/user.json" for 174.112.216.92 at 2014-06-17 03:53:56 +0000
Processing by Api::UserController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"test"=>"test", "user"=>{}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms`

Comment: it seems to be processing something it throws a 422 and I can't seem to figure out why @nyzm

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to put this line into your controller.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
  def create
    puts params
  end
end
```

As you are newbee so not for getting stuck into one thing use above method. And for details see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167956/rails-shows-warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-from-a-restkit-post)

And also check your **permitted params**.

Another solution to CSRF token is to pass it in headers like:

```
headers: {
  'X-Transaction': 'POST Example',
  'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why CSRF token is needed? @G.B

Comment: it is required for security purposes. for details see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html

Answer (score 0):

In the create action in your users controller, try redirecting to another page or rendering another view. I believe that will get rid of the routing errors.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def create
    puts params
    redirect_to(another_page)
  end
end
```